# Proof of differentiability

Tags: analysis

A function $f$ is defined in $R$, and $f'(0)$ exist.
Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ then prove that $f'$ exists for all $x$ in $R$.
I find this problem in here, 
and wonder the proof stated below has any problems?

Since $f'(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(0)(f(h)-1)}{h}=f(0)\lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}$
it means $\lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}$ exists.
$f'(x)==\lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(x)(f(h)-1)}{h}=f(x)\lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}$
thus $f'(x)$ exists if $f(x)$ exists.
But we can differentiate a function if it has a function value $f(x)$, thus  $f'$ exists for all $x$ in $R$.
I know it's not a perfect one,
just want to know it can be another way to solve that problem or not.

================================================================

$f(0)=0$ case:
If $f(0)=0$, because $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$,
$f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=0$ thus $f'(x)=f'(0)$.
Is that right?

Comment: You're right. That's my misspelling, I'll fix it.

Comment: When you say "Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$" do you mean that the equality holds for all $x,y$? (You are not "letting" anything, as $f$ was already given. One would "suppose" or "assume" the equality.)

Comment: Your solution is fine, there is one minor mistake though: When you conclude " It means0$ \lim_{h \rightarrow  0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}$" : what if $f(0)=0$? You should threat that case separately....

Comment: You forgot one case in your sketch. If $f(0)=0$, the limit you wrote does not exist. (And another comment appeared just before mine indicating the same issue.) On the other hand, this case is very easy to deal with.

Comment: Then, if I add $f(0)=0$ case, this proof can be a solution of that problem?

Comment: Definitely. One can polish the presentation a little bit, but the key idea is there, and the approach is efficient.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first part of your proof shows that $f'(x) = f(x) f'(0)$, hence $f$ is differentiable everywhere. For the second part, since $f(x) = f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)$, you have $f(x) = 0$ everywhere. It follows that $f'(x) = 0$.